# Find index of change in a column

Tags: r

Is there a way to find the indices of change of factors in a column with R? For example:

```
x <- c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd")
```

would return 3, 5, 6

Comment: Do you have a `factor` class there or you just calling it that way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try to compare shifted vectors, e.g.

```
which(x[-1] != x[-length(x)])
## [1] 3 5 6
```

This will work both on characters *and* factors

Comment: @Corey `x` in the question is a vector not a table, so I don't know why would expect it will have the same syntax. And I don't have your table so I have no idea what you are talking about and can't reproduce it.

Comment: The following solution is shorter https://stackoverflow.com/a/73911429/8806649

Comment: @Julien your solution doesn't work in base R. In case your `lag` functions comes from another package, then you should both specify it and it's not shorter than my solution because it adds dependencies when it's unnecessary. Finally, please don't advertise your solutions under other peoples solutions.

Comment: You're right, `lag` comes from `dplyr`

Answer (score 8):

```
which(!!diff(as.numeric(x)))
[1] 3 5 6
```

The assumption is that you really have factors. They are saved internally with numerical values. So when the difference is taken, a one will result at every change. A second coercion is that zeroes are considered FALSE and other numbers TRUE. `which` locates the TRUE values aka non-zeroes.

Comment: I'm curious about why you used `!!` instead of `as.logical`. Is it just because it's shorter type out? It's pretty neat

Comment: I really `!!` like this.

Comment: code-golfing. No one has time for all of that typing :)

Answer (score 5):

`rle` can be used for this:

```
head(cumsum(rle(x)$lengths), -1)
[1] 3 5 6
```

Comment: I do like David's solution better... this does not actually work for a `factor` without converting to `numeric` or `character` first.

Answer (score 0):

With the `dplyr::lag` function

```r
library(dplyr) 
which(x != lag(x)) - 1
# [1] 3 5 6
```