# Extract rows for change in variable, according to condition

Tags: r

My data includes time stamps of activities completed by athletes over different periods. Each period goes for a maximum of twenty minutes. The corresponding weather conditions are noted.

I want to call out the first occurrence of weather and when conditions change. My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944334/extract-rows-for-the-first-occurrence-of-a-variable-in-a-data-frame) except I want the first occurrence and when a change occurs.

My data is structured as follows:

```
  df <- data.frame(Time=c("0:00:00","0:01:00","0:02:40","0:12:09",
                        "0:00:00", "0:02:07","0:07:19","0:15:16",
                        "0:00:00", "0:03:00","0:08:40","0:13:29",
                        "0:00:00", "0:02:10","0:08:47","0:17:55"),
                 Athlete = c('Paul', 'Paul', 'Paul', 'Paul',
                             'Paul', 'Paul', 'Paul','Paul',
                            'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe',
                            'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe'),
                 Period = c('P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1',
                            'P2', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2',
                            'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1',
                            'P2', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2'),
                 Weather = c('Sunny', 'Sunny', 'Sunny', 'Cloudy',
                            'Rain', 'Cloudy', 'Rain', 'Rain',
                            'Rain', 'Sunny', 'Rain', 'Rain',
                            'Sunny', 'Sunny', 'Cloudy', 'Cloudy'))
```

1. How do I call out the first occurrence and change in weather, according to each athlete and period?
2. How do I have time in minutes.seconds? For example: 2.40

I have attempted the code below but this is not returning my anticipated output.

```
Test <- df[match(unique(df$Weather), df$Weather),]
```

My anticipated output would be:

```
Output <- data.frame(Time = c(0.0, 12.09, 
                              0.0, 2.07, 7.19, 
                              0.0, 3.00, 8.40, 
                              0.0, 8.47), 
                     Athlete = c('Paul', 'Paul', 
                                 'Paul', 'Paul', 'Paul',
                                 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe', 
                                 'Joe', 'Joe'), 
                     Period = c('P1', 'P1', 
                                'P2', 'P2', 'P2',
                                'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 
                                'P2', 'P2'), 
                     Weather = c('Sunny', 'Cloudy', 
                                 'Rain', 'Cloudy', 'Rain', 
                                 'Rain', 'Sunny', 'Rain', 
                                 'Sunny', 'Cloudy'))
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489277/find-index-of-change-in-a-column) question, I understand the index of a change in factors within a column can be located, how do I arrange this code to have my desired output?

Thank you.

Comment: `as.difftime(as.character(df$Time), format="%H:%M:%S")` if you are happy to not use lubridate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using something like `rleid` from "data.table". With that you can do:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[, ind := sequence(.N), rleid(Athlete, Period, Weather)][ind == 1]
##        Time Athlete Period Weather ind
##  1: 0:00:00    Paul     P1   Sunny   1
##  2: 0:12:09    Paul     P1  Cloudy   1
##  3: 0:00:00    Paul     P2    Rain   1
##  4: 0:02:07    Paul     P2  Cloudy   1
##  5: 0:07:19    Paul     P2    Rain   1
##  6: 0:00:00     Joe     P1    Rain   1
##  7: 0:03:00     Joe     P1   Sunny   1
##  8: 0:08:40     Joe     P1    Rain   1
##  9: 0:00:00     Joe     P2   Sunny   1
## 10: 0:08:47     Joe     P2  Cloudy   1
```

Regarding your question about "How do I have time in minutes.seconds? For example: 2.40--that's not really a standard way of expressing time, is it? `0.4 * 60 = 24`, so I wouldn't recommend converting it in that manner.

If you wanted those values as numeric values, perhaps you can split them out into separate columns. For that, I'd recommend my "splitstackshape" package.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(as.data.table(df)[
  , ind := sequence(.N), rleid(Athlete, Period, Weather)][ind == 1][
    , ind := NULL][], "Time", ":")
##     Athlete Period Weather Time_1 Time_2 Time_3
##  1:    Paul     P1   Sunny      0      0      0
##  2:    Paul     P1  Cloudy      0     12      9
##  3:    Paul     P2    Rain      0      0      0
##  4:    Paul     P2  Cloudy      0      2      7
##  5:    Paul     P2    Rain      0      7     19
##  6:     Joe     P1    Rain      0      0      0
##  7:     Joe     P1   Sunny      0      3      0
##  8:     Joe     P1    Rain      0      8     40
##  9:     Joe     P2   Sunny      0      0      0
## 10:     Joe     P2  Cloudy      0      8     47
```

"`Time_1`" would be hours, "`Time_2`" would be minutes, and "`Time_3`" would be seconds.

If you really wanted the "Time" column the way you described, you could do that with something like:

```
df$Time <- as.numeric(sub(":", ".", gsub("^[^:]*:", "", df$Time)))
```

And then, proceed with the "data.table" approach described earlier.

---

The "tidyverse" approach (still using `rleid` from "data.table") might look something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  mutate(ind = rleid(Athlete, Period, Weather)) %>%
  group_by(ind) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-ind) %>%
  mutate(Time = as.numeric(sub(":", ".", gsub("^[^:]*:", "", Time))))
# # A tibble: 10 × 4
#     Time Athlete Period Weather
#    <dbl>  <fctr> <fctr>  <fctr>
# 1   0.00    Paul     P1   Sunny
# 2  12.09    Paul     P1  Cloudy
# 3   0.00    Paul     P2    Rain
# 4   2.07    Paul     P2  Cloudy
# 5   7.19    Paul     P2    Rain
# 6   0.00     Joe     P1    Rain
# 7   3.00     Joe     P1   Sunny
# 8   8.40     Joe     P1    Rain
# 9   0.00     Joe     P2   Sunny
# 10  8.47     Joe     P2  Cloudy
```

Comment: If `Time` was in hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds, for example, 00:12:09:01, how would I please use your `gsub` code to extract 12.09?

Comment: @user2716568, there would be several ways. Here's one: `x <- "00:12:09:01"; gsub("^.*:(.*:.*):.*$", "\\1", x)`.

Comment: Apologies for another question, but how would I extract use your code to extract the minutes.seconds from a column containing hours.minutes.seconds:milliseconds in a data.frame `df$Time`

Comment: @user2716568, Are you familiar with regular expressions? Regular expressions use parentheses to capture groups. In the comment above, I only captured one group (and returned it with `"\\1"`. You can use multiple groups of parentheses to capture multiple groups of data.

Comment: @user2716568, also, that's why I had suggested the `cSplit` approach to split into multiple columns in one go, and deal with the data from there....

Comment: I am very sorry but I am not familiar with regular expressions. How would I adapt the following code: `df$Time <- as.numeric(sub(":", ".", gsub("^[^:]*:", "", df$Time)))` to now read hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138495/discussion-between-a5c1d2h2i1m1n2o1r2t1-and-user2716568).

Answer (score 1):

The not super elegant version:

```
df %>% filter(c(1,diff(as.numeric(Athlete)))!=0 |
              c(1,diff(as.numeric(Weather)))!=0 |
              c(1,diff(as.numeric(Period)))!=0)
```

Note that this requires the data to be sorted the right way.